# how to set the path to a folder on google storage bucket using google cloud functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, boto

I'm using Python on Google Cloud Functions. For the package corenlp I need to set the path to the jar folder. I usually do thin on my local computer:

```
os.environ["CORENLP_HOME"] = r'/home/user/stanfordnlp_resources/stanford-corenlp-latest/stanford-corenlp-4.1.0/'
```

But how can I do it on Google Cloud Functions? I have uploaded the folder to the bucket and I need to set the path to the folder on the bucket in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You specify environment variables at the time you deploy with gcloud.  Please see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).  You will use the [--set-env-vars](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--set-env-vars) flag.

However, if your library requires a local file to read at runtime, using a reference to a file in Cloud Storage will not work.  You would have to download it to /tmp and reference it from there.